# I can't get the data I want from Mongodb like {{Users.1.title}}

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

controller

```
  exports.getShowPost = (req, res) => {
      Post.findById(req.params.id)
        .then((data) => {
          const post = data.toObject();
          res.render('post/show', {
            'post' : post
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
          res.status(500).send();
        });
    };
```

How can I call the data I want to the page?
{{post.title}} works fine. I want it as {{user.1.title}}. I couldn't convert postid to postfind

Comment: More code examples are necessary. What does the data in your collection look like, for example? What specific issue is there with your current small code example, if any?

Comment: h1 id="oyun-ust-ismi">{{post.title}} Oyunu!</h1>
<iframe class="oyun" src="{{{post.gamelink}}}" id="TamEkran" allowfullscreen</iframe>.            this is working. but I can't call something like {{posts.1.title}}